# Calculus Kinematic Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, kinematics

"A body moves in a straight line such that, *t* s after passing through a fixed point *O*, its displacement from *O* is *s* m. The velocity *v* ms^-1 of the body is such that v = 5cos(4t)"

a) Write down the velocity of the body as it passes through *O*.

b) Find the value of *t* when the acceleration of the body is first equal to 10ms^-2 .

For a) I got v = 5ms^1 .

For b) I did the following:

dv/dt = -20sin(4t)

10 = -20sin(4t)

-0.5 = sin(4t)

How do I get rid of the sine? Do I use the arcsine? When I do that I get 4t = (-1/6)pi , and after I divide it by 4 I get (-1/24)pi, which is not the correct answer... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since time got no directions(at least in kinematics), don't take $-pi/6$ as the value. Since it is mentioned that the first time the acceleration goes to $10 ms^-2$. The value will be $4t= 210$. So the answer will be $52.5 sec$

Comment: Why would it be 210 though? I used the value -1/6pi since that was what I got from the division. The answer given by the book is t =(7/24)pi, and I cannot figure out exactly why. What does the part "first time" suggest?

Comment: Since the acceleration is in terms of sine and the sine value will repeat after one complete rotation i.e., after 360 deg.

Comment: @KakaS you should be using radians not degrees

Comment: Yeah....210 deg is 7*pi/6 which would give the answer.Thanks @David Quinn

Comment: Oh, right! -1/6pi is the same as 7/6pi when you go "the other way round". A question though. Why wouldn't -1/6pi be a suitable answer?  Just because it is negative?

Comment: Yes...in this case since it is the time we are after.